# Django 2.0.6 ошибка 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

Tags: python-3.x, django

Установил виртуальное окружение с параметром `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv` (пробовал и 3.5). В wsgi скрипте указал `os.environ.setdefault('VIRTUAL_ENV', '/var/www/env')`. В виртуальном окружении установил Django 2.0.6 (установилась без ошибок). При переходе на страницу сайта в логе ошибка:

> File "/var/www/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 61, in 
>     @functools.lru_cache()
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

Проверка версии питона `python -V` говорит версию 3.5.2.
В настройке Apache в "VirtualHost" указано:

> WSGIDaemonProcess djangosite display-name=djangosite lang='en_US.UTF-8' locale='en_US.UTF-8'
>
> WSGIProcessGroup djangosite
>
> WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/wsgi.py

Подскажите куда копать и что я сделал не так

Comment: wsgi скрипт запускается кем?

Comment: Скорее всего, запуск через `python 2`.

Comment: Поздравляю, в апаче Python 2.7. Откажитесь от его использования и поставьте что-нибудь нормальное, например gunicorn

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек! Настроил с nginx + gunicorn и все завелось.